# Manually removing padding added by RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, padding

I am using PKCS11 with SunJCE to decrypt byte data.Data is being encrypted using RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING which is not compatible with PKCS11. So I will have to remove it manually, but no luck till now. Following is my attempt to remove it RSA_KEY_SIZE is 2048:

```
if (paddedPlainText.length < RSA_KEY_SIZE / 8) {
   byte[] tmp = new byte[RSA_KEY_SIZE / 8];
   System.arraycopy(paddedPlainText, 0, tmp, tmp.length - paddedPlainText.length, paddedPlainText.length);
   System.out.println("Zero padding to " + (RSA_KEY_SIZE / 8));
   paddedPlainText = tmp;
}

OAEPParameterSpec paramSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, pSrc);
RSAPadding padding = RSAPadding.getInstance(RSAPadding.PAD_OAEP_MGF1, RSA_KEY_SIZE / 8, new SecureRandom(), paramSpec);
byte[] plainText = padding.unpad(paddedPlainText);
```

Comment: `MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256` should probably be `MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1`

Comment: Tried with `MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1`, but no luck.

Comment: @ArtjomB Thanks, it actually worked with `MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256`, the response that we were getting was encrypted and then Base64 encoded, so I just had to decode the encrypted string before actually trying for decryption.